# Subscribe to channel not working - Parse with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Before you say anything - yes I know that Parse are closing :) Yet I really need this.

I am trying to subscribe to channel, like it is [documented in Parse](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-using-channels).
But I don't see the channel that I've added in the Core screen. I am sure that the version is correct.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("myChannel", forKey: "channels")
    currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
```

I tried adding `"myChannel"` into array like this:

```
let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.addUniqueObject(["myChannel"], forKey: "channels")
    currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
As **Shubank** sujjested I tried the following:

```
let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("beybey", forKey: "channels")
    currentInstallation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (bool: Bool, error: NSError?) in
        print(bool)
        print(error)
    }
```

The breakpoint inside the block wasn't triggered.

Comment: is the function being called ? you can also try passing a  error/result callback to the `saveInBackground` method

Comment: @Shubhank, the code is being called. How do I pass error/result?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/osx/api/Categories/PFObject(Deprecated).html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(im)saveInBackgroundWithTarget:selector:

Comment: It's deprecated. They sujjested to use this: https://www.parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(im)saveInBackgroundWithBlock: But the breakpoint inside the block wasn't triggered. I've updated my question

Comment: `let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()` print this variable and check if it is not nil

Comment: @Shubhank, You are corect! The currentInstallation is nil. Or more specifically: print currentInstallation gave
(PFInstallation) $R1 = <uninitialized>

Comment: @Shubhank Put this as an answer and I'll check it as correct. In fact what helped me was to call this function after delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current installation is nil at the place where you are accessing it.

Probably wait for a token to be registered for remote notification to be accessed till its instance is created